# simple six-position voting machine into a 7 position voting machine

Tags: digital-logic, cmos, adder

I'm new to learning about full and half adders and what not. but I am struggling to understand this question out of my study manual.

The pictures shows a simple six-position voting machine module using CMOS logic. what change could you make to the module to allow a seventh position? (hint: no ICs are needed.)[image]

If I could ask for some assistance on figuring this out, that would be flat out awesome!

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is \$C_0\$ in each parallel adder?

Comment: Thanks for you comment

Comment: I had been hoping you'd get a chance to see for yourself how this works. One thing you should keep in mind that when you are asked a question like that, go look around for grounded pins that don't seem to be doing anything practical. Chances are, that's where your answer lays. Good to see you have an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hook up the C0 pin on both 4-bit adders to the 7th yes-no switch.

Comment: So instead of C0 going to ground, have the leads from the switch go to each one of the parallel adders.

is that because the C0 is an input of some sort?

Thanks for you help!

Comment: Yes. C0 is the carry input. You can add another 1 here.

Answer (score 0):

Add a 7th switch in parallel to one of the existing ones?